# Thread-safety of int field in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, java-threads, happens-before

If class has field with int type (not Atomic Integer and without volatile keyword) and all access to this field happens under read/write locks - will this field thread-safe in this case? Or in some moment some thread can see not real value of this field but something from cache?

```
public static class Example {
        private int isSafe;
        private final ReadWriteLock lock;
        
        public Example(int i) {
            isSafe = i;
            lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
        }
        
        public int getIsSafe() {
            final Lock lock = this.lock.readLock();
            lock.lock();
            try {
                return isSafe;
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }

        public void someMethod1() {
            final Lock lock = this.lock.writeLock();
            lock.lock();
            try {
                isSafe++;
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: It is important to understand that caches on modern cpus are always coherent due to the cache coherence protocol like MESI. Another important thing to understand is that correctly synchronized programs exhibit sequential consistent behavior and for sequential consistency the real time order isnt relevant. So reads and writes can be skewed as long as nobody can observe a violation of the program order.

Comment: In short, the above program is correctly synchronized because it doesnt contain any dataraces.

Comment: @pveentjer, Can you say that the _program_ is correctly synchronized when you haven't seen most of it? The _class,_ `Example` is "thread-safe" in the sense that it provides certain useful guarantees\* that hold true regardless of how many different threads operate on the same `Example` instance. [\* E.g., if `getIsSafe()` is called when the program is otherwise quiescent, then the value returned is _guaranteed_ to be equal to the `i` given in the constructor call plus the number of prior calls to `someMethod1()`.] But, the program still could use an `Example` instance in an "unsafe" algorithm.

Comment: @SolomonSlow quiescence is no guarantee for sequential consistency to see latest value since that implies preserving the real time ordering which seqiential consistence doesn't need to preserve. You need linearizability, quiescence consistence  or strict serializability for that.

Comment: @pveentjer, I'm pretty sure that when one thread releases the write lock in `someMethod1`, it _happens before_ any other thread can subsequently acquire the read lock in `getIsSafe`. Maybe I guess I made a mistake when I said "...program is quiescent..." I should have said, quiescent and _no thread is in a call to either method._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get answer from @pveentjer in comments under question:

> It is important to understand that caches on modern cpus are always
> coherent due to the cache coherence protocol like MESI. Another
> important thing to understand is that correctly synchronized programs
> exhibit sequential consistent behavior and for sequential consistency
> the real time order isnt relevant. So reads and writes can be skewed
> as long as nobody can observe a violation of the program order.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This approach is thread-safe. If there is no thread that has requested the write lock and the lock for writing, then multiple threads can lock the lock for reading. It means multiple threads can read the data at the very moment, as long as there’s no thread to write the data or to update the data.